# is it possible to use any html encrypter to encrypt paypal html code?

Tags: php, html, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have an html pay now button (buy now) i have to host it on my own server and remove the protection in order for it to do what i want it to do, (a programmer who works at paypal told me what i have to do, so i can't argue with him)

now that the button works just how i want it to work, I need to encrypt it, I've been googling for a about 2 weeks or so, and i found many ways to get the job done, but i want the best and simplest way to encrypt it, because i'm new to the paypal world so i don't want to follow a tutorial that would take me a month to understand

does the standard html encrypt, do the job? I doubt that but i have to ask it anyway. If there's a simple way to do it in the server side, I'll be so happy

**What do I mean by simple?**

I don't mind following a long step by step tutorial to get it done, as long as it is a step by step tutorial

**EDIT**

Here's the code of my button (i have changed it a bit but you can see everything you need to know)

```
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="KU515658J">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="5">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_paynow_SM.gif:NonHosted">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="example">example</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="os0" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynow_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

As I said I had to remove the code protection so now you can see the value, using firebug or google chrome inspect element tool, or whatever and all you need is to change it, it doesn't take a hacker to do it

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="5">
```

By the way my website is in php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### If you can make an API call using PHP/cURL, use the Button Manager API

You can call the 'create button' API and tell PayPal to make an encrypted button for you with all the variables and values you want.

- [Button Manager API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ButtonMgrAPIIntro)

---

### Otherwise, use Encrypted Website Payments

This will use your server's resources to encrypt the button, and you will need to find a way to code a solution to encrypt the PayPal button before generating it (also requiring PHP or other server side scripting languages).

- [Encrypted Website Payments](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_encryptedwebpayments#id08A3I0P017Q)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to encrypt the button HTML, or the data it sends?

In relation to the former: there will always be around HTML encryption; you can't actually encrypt HTML in a secure way - someone will always find a way round your encryption as HTML has to be parseable by the browser.

In the latter case, PayPal uses `https://` and SSL when sending data to it's server, so that's (nearly) as safe as it gets. The data is encrypted so packet sniffers have a hard time figuring out what's going on. If you look at the PayPal form code, you'll see that not a lot of information is sent, the most vulnerable being an ID that is verified by PayPal anyway.

PayPal and the like put a lot of work into security. You shouldn't be worrying about "encrypting" your HTML.

---

You have a syntax error in this piece of code `<td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="example button"</td>` - you need a `>` after `"example button"`. In relation to being able to change the value, you should check on the PayPal side of things to see if PayPal validates the value server-side. If it doesn't, there isn't a way to make this any more secure and is a huge issue on PayPal's part.

Comment: sir i need to encrypt them both, i have been able to change the value of my button from 2.99$ to 4$ using the inspect element window in google chrome, you can see it clearly

Comment: _How_ have you managed to do that? Also, can you post your button code (minus any sensitive information) in your question?

Comment: no sir, I checked the site, i have no error on the site, the error was only here and fixed it